# Animation On Local Position

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to make this:

The chracter walks up to a large crate, the player presses the <kbd>e</kbd> key and an animation starts playing, such that the character climbs up on to the crate. (all in first person view).

So far I tried this with normal "First Person Controller" Prefab in Unity.

My code so far:

```c#
function OnTriggerStay(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "GrabZone"){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("e")){
            animation.Play("JumpToLedge");
        }
    }
}
```

However when I use this on the FPC, it will always play from the position the animation is created on. I also tried to create an empty game object, placing the FPC in there. Gives same effect.

Most recently, I tried just animating the graphics of the FPC alone. This seems to work, but since the Character Controller itself is not animated, that stays on the ground. So the whole FPC won't work anymore.

Is there anyway I could let this animation play on the local position the player is on at that time? Or can you think of any other logical solution for a grab and climb?

Answer (score 1):

You should always animate from the 0,0 position. This way you can always easilyl determine what to do and where to go with your model.